# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

What could be the reason for this error being thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/sc/sc.py", line 30, in <module>
    driver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/sc/sc.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver = Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/sc/sc.py", line 36, in <module>
    driver = Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

List item
```

For this code:

```
from time import time, sleep

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from args_parser import ArgsParser
from downloader import download_file

args = ArgsParser()


def print_if_verbose(val):
    if args.output_verbose:
        print(val)


WAITING_TIMEOUT = 180
chrome_options = Options()
driver_user_agent = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                     '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={driver_user_agent}')
if not args.display_browser:
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
try:
    driver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    try:
        driver = Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
    except Exception:
        driver = Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
```

BTW, I have Chrome 114 on macOS M2 silicon, and using Python 3.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, but `options`. (That's why it complains that you're passing it in twice.)

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now. Example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=r'./chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Also note that a driver manager is now built-in to selenium, so you no longer need to use the separate `webdriver_manager`. The Selenium Team talked about that here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/selenium-manager-best-tool-from-you-can-forget-david-burns/

Comment: This is an exact copy of your answer yesterday. Just flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Mostly, but implemented differently. I added a paragraph at the end about how the driver manager is included with selenium now, making ``webdriver_manager`` unnecessary.